i try to set up a new resolution using xrandr. but nothing is happen. (Upuntu 23.10)
First i Run 'xrandr' command:
elhennawy@elhennawy-01:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-I-2 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      59.92*+
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77

and then i run those commands:
$ cvt 1400 1050
$ xrandr --newmode "1400x1050_60.00"  121.75  1400 1488 1632 1864  1050 1053 1057 1089 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode DVI-I-2 1400x1050_60.00

and nothing is change!.How can i to fix this?
nothing is change!

The first list created by xrandr shows you the modes available for this given monitor. The line
1024x768      59.92*+

tells you, that it is currently running at the resolution 1024x768 at a frequency of 59.92Hz. This is indicated by the + sign at the end. The first line Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767 only relates to the capabilities of the Xserver, meaning that it can handle this maximum virtual resolution in software, but not necessarily in hardware (here: your monitor).
Your attempts to set your monitor to 1400x1050px at 60Hz fail, because your monitor/output device does not support this. You can derive this from the first list, because this combination of resolution and frequency is not listed.
The information about the capabilities of your monitor are gained via EDMI/DDC, a communication standard to handle the data exchange between your computer and your monitor.
